# Как у TTrackBar поменять цвет фона и бегунка?

Tags: delphi, компоненты, vcl

Как в Delphi 10.2 поменять цвет фона и бегунка для `TTrackBar`? Никаких `Color`, `Background`, `Foreground` в свойствах нет.

Comment: Если речь о VCL, то TTrackBar  - системный контрол и использует настройки Windows

Comment: Да, это VCL, понятно, что системный контрол. Но вот есть там например TProgressBar, тоже VCL, так у него можно менять цвет фона и самой полосы.

Comment: У ProgressBar изначально заложена такая возможность в элементе управления Windows, например `PBM_SETBARCOLOR Sets the color of the progress indicator bar in the progress bar control`, а у трекбара простыми средствами можно только поменять `Brush.Color` (вряд ли понравится). Что-то, вероятно, можно предпринять при обработке `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`

Comment: Здесь: https://torry.net/pages.php?id=158 ничего подходящего нет?

Comment: К сожалению нет (

Comment: В RXLib (а значит, и в Jedi VCL) есть Slider (тот же TrackBar), у которого можно задавать цвет фона, битмапы бегунка и центральной полоски.

Comment: Я скачал JVCLd9pPatch. для Delphi 10.2 подойдет?

Comment: В Delphi 6 был кажется TSliderBar в стандартных компонентах. Странно, Delphi 10.2 его нет...

Comment: Я  JVCL не пользовался и по совместимости точно не скажу. Знаю только, что многие компоненты RXLib туда перешли.

Comment: А для чего это всё нужно, кстати?

Comment: Что именно все? Мне по идее нужно только цвет поля у TTrackBar поменять, согласно заданию по работе.

Comment: Rxlib (пакеты с Data можно и не устанавливать): http://www.micrel.cz/RxLib/dfiles.htm

Answer (score 4):

В комментарии вам правильно ответили, что TTrackBar - системный контроль, поэтому просто свойства его вы не поменяете. Но если очень хочется, то:

1. Использовать Skins
2. Использовать другой компонент, реализующий те же самые возможности. (Как вариант: взять исходники Vcl.ComCtrls и сделать самому, но я не уверен, что всё просто получится).
3. Создавать свой класс-наследник, перехватывая отрисовку. Как-то так:

---

```
type
  TTrackBar=class(ComCtrls.TTrackBar)
   private
      procedure MyPaint(var w:TWMPaint); message WM_Paint;
      procedure MyEraseBG(var w:TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_EraseBkgnd;
  end;
```

Ну, а что вы там создадите - уже ваше видение. Например, как обрабатывать стирание:

```
procedure TTrackBar.MyEraseBG(var w: TWMEraseBkgnd);
var Rect:TRect;
begin
 with Rect do
    begin
      Left:=0;
      Top:=0;
      Right:=Width-1;
      Bottom:=Height-1;
    end; // получили координаты стираемого
 with TCanvas.Create do begin // нам надолго не нужно, даже переменную не будем объявлять
   Handle:=w.DC;
     // Теперь мы можем рисовать, что хотим, используя, например, наш Rect в качестве координат
      // можно даже картинки использовать
   Free; // не забываем освободить наш временный Canvas
 end;
end;
```

Точно так же обрабатываем отрисовку, не забывая использовать свойство Position, проверять, изменилось оно и т.п. Только вот тип TWMPaint отличается от TWMEraseBkgnd, поэтому надо делать финт ушами (тут не совсем помню, а Delphi, чтобы проверить, под рукой нет), нет, судя по справке, то же самое, только сильно рекомендуют проверку на 0 делать:

```
if w.DC=0 then exit; // лучше проверить!
 with TCanvas.Create do begin
    Handle:=w.DC;
   // тут наши безобразия
    Free;
 end;
```

Comment: Хорошо, допустим, я выбрал пункт 3. Но тогда в теле процедур MyPaint и MyEraseBG как отрисовывать фон? Может так - посылать или постить сообщение: SendMessage(MyTrackBar.Handle, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, clRed) ?

Comment: Как хотите. Фактически, вы делаете это с нуля... Хорошо, давайте добавлю немного кода :)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: Вроде что-то получается, но мне нужно только изменить цвет области по которому передвигается бегунок. Никак не могу разобраться, какой параметр отвечает за это.

Comment: @AVM Если сам всё делаешь, сам всё и задаёшь, и область рисуешь. Всякие скины на этом и построены. Всё-таки стоит посмотреть в исходниках, как устроен компонент

Answer (score 3):

Я не автор вопроса, но ответ уважаемого **Viktor Tomilov** не работает вовсе, хотя вроде должен. Пробовал на `Delphi Starter 10.2 Tokyo`.

Зато вот что удалось найти по вопросу отрисовки на ресурсах `Microsoft`:
[Уведомления класса TrackBar](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Controls/bumper-trackbar-control-reference-notifications)
[Уведомление NM_CUSTOMDRAW](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Controls/nm-customdraw-trackbar)

И на сладкое - [готовый TrackBar с кастомной отрисовкой](http://www.heelana.com/VCL/ThlTrackBar/thltrackbar.html), датированный 2003 годом. Автором компонента является **Nicolas Reinschmidt**.

Цитата с сайта автора:

> ThlTrackBar is a descendant of the VCL TTrackBar component. It adds the custom draw functionality that is actually provided by the underlying Windows TrackBar control but is not exposed in the VCL TTrackBar wrapper.
>
> The OnCustomDraw event allows for drawing custom ticks, thumb and channel (track). You are free to choose which item you like to draw yourself. If you want to keep the default appearance for one of the items set the DefaultDraw parameter to true in your OnCustomDraw event handler for that particular item.

Примерный вид решения приведен на картинке ниже (изображение взято с сайта, доступного по ссылке выше (справедливо на 30.06.2018)).

[image: Примерный вид решения]

Comment: Спасибо, попробую этот пример. На самом деле, предыдущий пример не работает (

Comment: Спасибо, этот пример подходит!

Comment: @AVM, рад, что все удачно. Если пример действительно подошел, то Вы можете нажать на галочку рядом с моим ответом, чтобы пометить его как окончательный.